# Confused with selection of d3.js version 3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am playing with d3.js version 3 (Sorry, it is not 4.) and get confused of its nested selection.

In the following code I intended to animate 3-depth binary tree of cells contain the current time:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <script>
      function f(){
        var ps0 = d3.select("body");

        var ps1 = ps0.selectAll("div").data([new Date(), new Date()]);
        ps1.enter().append("div").style("background", "red");
        ps1.text(function (x){return "red " + x;});
        ps1.exit().remove();

        var ps2 = ps1.selectAll("div").data([new Date(), new Date()]);
        ps2.enter().append("div").style("background", "green");
        ps2.text(function (x){return "green " + x;});
        ps2.exit().remove();

        var ps3 = ps2.selectAll("div").data([new Date(), new Date()]);
        ps3.enter().append("div").style("background", "blue");
        ps3.text(function (x){return "blue " + x;});
        ps3.exit().remove();
      }

      setInterval("f()", 1000);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

At the first call, it draws exactly what I want: 2 red, 4 green and 8 blue cells.  But from the second call, it only draw the first half and the latter is get removed.

I guess I misunderstand something around d3's nested selection but still cannot find out why it works like this and how to fix it.  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Now I understand selectAll traverses not only the direct children nodes but also all the descendants of the current selection from top to bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When  you do this:

```
var ps1 = ps0.selectAll("div")...
var ps2 = ps1.selectAll("div")...
var ps3 = ps2.selectAll("div")...
```

You are selecting **pre-existing** divs, and binding data to them. That's not what you want.

Solution: for each selection, select only the divs belonging to that selection. An easy way to do that is setting and selecting by class:

```
var ps1 = ps0.selectAll(".ps1")
    //select by class -----^
    .data([new Date(), new Date()]);

ps1.enter().append("div")
    .style("background", "red")
    .attr("class", "ps1");
    //set the class --^
```

Here is your updated code:

```js
function f() {
  var ps0 = d3.select("body");

  var ps1 = ps0.selectAll(".ps1").data([new Date(), new Date()]);
  ps1.enter().append("div").style("background", "red").attr("class", "ps1");
  ps1.text(function(x) {
    return "red " + x;
  });
  ps1.exit().remove();

  var ps2 = ps1.selectAll(".ps2").data([new Date(), new Date()]);
  ps2.enter().append("div").style("background", "green").attr("class", "ps2");
  ps2.text(function(x) {
    return "green " + x;
  });
  ps2.exit().remove();

  var ps3 = ps2.selectAll(".ps3").data([new Date(), new Date()]);
  ps3.enter().append("div").style("background", "blue").attr("class", "ps3");
  ps3.text(function(x) {
    return "blue " + x;
  });
  ps3.exit().remove();
}

setInterval(f, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```